# Preventing converting string into octal number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

Assume we have following ruby code

```
require 'yaml'

h={"key"=>[{"step1"=>["0910","1223"]}]}
puts h.to_yaml
```

`"0910"` is a string
but after `to_yaml` conversion, string turns into octal number.

```
---
key:
- step1:
  - 0910
  - '1223'
```

the problem is I cannot change `h` variable. I receive it from outside, and I need to solve problem without changing it.

Comment: Did you try to parse it back?

Answer (score 4):

You are mistaken that there is an octal number in your YAML output. The [YAML spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764652) refers to octal on two occasions, and both clearly indicate that an octal number in a YAML file starts with `0o` (which is a similar to what Ruby and newer versions of Python use for specifying octal; Python also dropped the support for `0` only octals in version 3, Ruby doesn't seem to have done that—yet).

The custom to indicate octal integers starting with a `0` only, has been proven confusing in many language and was dropped from the YAML specification six years ago. It might be that your parser still supports it, but it shouldn't.

In any case the characters `8` and `9` can never occur in an integer represented as an octal number, so in this case there can be no confusion that that unquoted scalar is a number.
The string 1223 could be interpreted as a normal integer, therefore it must always be represented as a quoted string scalar.

The interesting thing would be to see what happens when you dump the string `"0708"`. If your YAML library is up-to-date with the spec (version 1.2) it can just dump this as an unquoted scalar. Because of the leading zero that is not followed by `o` (or `x`) there can be no confusion that this could be an octal number (resp. hexadecimal) either, but for compatibility with old parsers (from before 2009) your parser might just quote it to be on the safe side.

Comment: to check what will happen while dumping 0708 I've used this piece of code.
    
    require 'psych'

    h={"key"=>[{"step1"=>['0910',"1223","0708","08","0777"]}]}
    puts Psych.dump(h)`

the sesult:

    ---
    key:
    - step1:
      - 0910
      - '1223'
      - 0708
      - 08
      - '077'

Comment: @user3419308 So either the parser is 1.2 and plays it safe wrt octal characters or it is only YAML 1.1 compatible. The other thing you could try is specifying `0o77` (without quotes) and see if that loads (sorry I don't have ruby installed on my system, so can't try this out myself).

Comment: How do you think, what is the best solution to avoid this conversion?

Comment: @user3419308 I'm not sure what you mean by conversion. A ruby string gets represented, either as a simple scalar if it can, or as a quoted scalar if necessary. My (Python) YAML library has an option to specify how to represent string scalars by default, and that way you can force it to quote everything. If your library doesn't have such an option, you have to live with the representation it chooses (which is IMO not a conversion)

Answer (score 1):

According the the YAML [spec](http://yaml.org/type/int.html) numbers prefixed with a 0 signal an octal base (as does in Ruby). However 08 is not a valid octal number, so it doesn't get quoted.

When you come to load this data from the YAML file, the data appears exactly as you need.

```rb
0> h={"key"=>[{"step1"=>["0910","1223"]}]}
=> {"key"=>[{"step1"=>["0910", "1223"]}]}

0> yaml_h = h.to_yaml
=> "---\nkey:\n- step1:\n  - 0910\n  - '1223'\n"

0> YAML.load(yaml_h)
=> {"key"=>[{"step1"=>["0910", "1223"]}]}
```

If you can't use the data in this state perhaps you could expand on the question and give more detail.

Comment: You are referencing a spec that is more than 6 years old. YAML 1.2 specifies that octal numbers should start with `0o`. It could of course be that the library tries to be backward compatible, but that cannot be deduced from this limited input.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar task.
I use in secrets.yml:

```
processing_eth_address: "0x5774226def39e67d6afe6f735f9268d63db6031b"
```

OR

```
processing_eth_address: <%= "\'#{ENV["PROCESSING_ETH_ADDRESS"]}\'" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Ruby doesn't do this octal conversion but I had a similar issue with dates.  I used to_yaml(canonical: true) to get around this issue.  It's more verbose but it's *correct*.

```
{"date_of_birth" => "1991-02-29"}.to_yaml
=> "---\ndate_of_birth: 1991-02-29\n"
{"date_of_birth" => "1991-02-29"}.to_yaml(canonical: true)
=> "---\n{\n  ? \"date_of_birth\"\n  : \"1991-02-29\",\n}\n"
```