# Unexpected mode behaviour from the template module when mode is starting with a zero

Tags: ansible

I'm not sure if I'm facing an Ansible bug. I'm using this Ansible version:

```bash
ansible [core 2.13.4]
  ...
  python version = 3.8.9 (default, Apr 13 2022, 08:48:07) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Something weird happens when I execute these tasks:

```yaml
- name: template a file
  template:
    src: test.j2
    dest: /tmp/one
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0775

- name: template 2 files in a loop
  template:
    src: test.j2
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
  loop:
    - dest: /tmp/two
      mode: 0775
    - dest: /tmp/three
      mode: 0644
```

On the first task, the mode on disk is set to `0775`, no issues there.
Now for the second task, Ansible outputs the following:

```
failed: [vm-local-1] (item={'dest': '/tmp/one', 'mode': 509}) => changed=false
  ansible_loop_var: item
  checksum: 4678e30d172cb68ff1dab229babb736671d75d26
  details: 'bad symbolic permission for mode: 509'
  gid: 0
  group: root
  item:
    dest: /tmp/one
    mode: 509
  mode: '0775'
  msg: mode must be in octal or symbolic form
  owner: root
  path: /tmp/one
  secontext: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
  size: 12
  state: file
  uid: 0
ok: [vm-local-1] => (item={'dest': '/tmp/two', 'mode': 420})
```

This doesn't occur when the `mode` values are quoted.

Am I facing an Ansible bug, or is this somehow expected behaviour?

Comment: This is a YAML parsing issue, quote them. `0644` for YAML is an octal value. So you end up with the int 420 (644 octal to decimal conversion).

Comment: But this doesn't explain why it 'works' in the first task, but 'breaks' in the loop, right?

Comment: It is also somehow documented [`template` mdoule - Parameter `mode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#parameter-mode) "_... so Ansible receives a string and can do its own conversion from string into number._"

Comment: Small tip for the editor, to have a real newline between two sentences, you can end the first one with **two** spaces before the newline, you don't need that backslash :)

Comment: `You must either add a leading zero so that Ansible’s YAML parser knows it is an octal number`. That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: As we can see from the original description the issue becomes introduced by `loop` not the template module itself. We would need to have a look into the the content of `item.mode` additionally with `type_debug`. Furthermore a test with `mode: "{{ item.mode | quote }}"`

Comment: @KevinC well, true indeed, but that's what the error you get in the details means: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/42563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned within the comments the issue becomes introduced by `loop` and the YAML parser.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Type debug
    debug:
      msg: "item.mode is {{ item.mode }} of type {{ item.mode | type_debug }}"
    loop:
      - dest: /tmp/two
        mode: 0775
      - dest: /tmp/three
        mode: 0644
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Type debug] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/two', u'mode': 509}) =>
  msg: item.mode is 509 of type int
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/three', u'mode': 420}) =>
  msg: item.mode is 420 of type int
```

Whereby quoted values for `mode` in `loop` would result into

```yaml
TASK [Type debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/two', u'mode': u'0775'}) =>
  msg: item.mode is 0775 of type AnsibleUnicode
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/three', u'mode': u'0644'}) =>
  msg: item.mode is 0644 of type AnsibleUnicode
```

and

> "*Ansible receives a string and can do its own conversion from string into number.*"

You should remove the leading zeros resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Type debug] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/two', u'mode': 775}) =>
  msg: item.mode is 775 of type int
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'dest': u'/tmp/three', u'mode': 644}) =>
  msg: item.mode is 644 of type int
```

and to avoid unwanted type conversion.

> *Am I facing an Ansible bug, or is this somehow expected behaviour?*

To summarize, it is caused by the leading zeros in the `loop` variables, it is not bug, it is the expected behaviour.

**Further Reading**

- Ansible Issue #[42563](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/42563)
- [Avoid leading zeros in numeric values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/yaml-tips.html#avoid-leading-zeros)
- [[YAML] Parsing octal numbers: unexpected value conversion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34807)
- [Preventing converting string into octal number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33099062/6771046)

Comment: Quite strange behaviour, I just didn't expect it at all.